Sample weights in Xgboost regression
I am trying to fit a regression model using xgboost's XGBRegressor where I overweight more recent data vs the past during training. I am wondering how the sample_weight works for xgboost.
I know that for tree-based models, the fitting basically splits data into various nodes/buckets then take the average of the observations within the bucket. This is where I hope someone more knowledgable about xgboost can explain how sample weight plays into this. I believe in most regressions, the sample weights are just a multiplier for the observations when calculating the loss function during fitting. If that's the case for xgboost, then while sample_weight would affect how algorithm choose the splits, it would still weight all observations the same when taking the average within each bucket. Does anyone know if this is true? Is there a way to specify in xgboost that I want to reduce certain observations' weights when taking the average within the node/bucket?

This is another question where the easiest solution is the Nike approach: just do it
Here I'm generating some data y that has mean zero and then upweighting the positive values of y
> x<-rep(0:1,each=50)
> y<-rnorm(100)
> w<-1+5*(y>0)
> xgboost(as.matrix(x),y,weight=w,nrounds=2)
> xgboost(as.matrix(x),y,weight=w,nrounds=2)->xx
[1] train-rmse:0.850042 
[2] train-rmse:0.848664 

> predict(xx,newdata=as.matrix(c(0,1)))
[1] 0.5612160 0.5350527

The predictive means are not about zero, they are about 0.6, so the weights must have been applied to computing the means in each bucket
